# Remove Title Bar ios-simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

How do I remove the title bar from the
[ios simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6rW6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to tell you that but there is no way to hide the toolbar. It is a toolbar integrated to iOS Simulator that has no effect on your code/app. The only way it could be changed is through an Xcode/iOS Simulator Update from Apple.

Comment: Do you have any information as to why the title bar was implemented?